# Validação de JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing

Eu preciso validar três datas que são do tipo `JDateChooser`.
Essas datas são: data de nascimento, data de admissão e data de demissão.

A data de nascimento não pode ser maior que a data de admissão e nem maior que a data de demissão.

A data de demissão não pode ser menor que a data de admissão.

Eu quero validar a data de admissão no momento que o usuário preencher, será disparada uma janela de alerta caso essa data for menor que a data de nascimento. E o mesmo acontece entre a data de admissão e a data de demissão.

Já tentei fazer essa validação com um if - else, mas só funciona para dois casos ao mesmo tempo, ou apenas para um. E utilizei o evento `mouseEntered` e setei um valor mínimo para as datas. Mas tenho esse erro

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

.
Alguém teria uma sugestão ?
Obrigada.

Tentativa 1

```
if(dataAdm().getDate().after(dataNasc.getDate())){
      if(dataDem().getDate().after(DataAdm.getDate())){
          mensagem de alerta;
      }
    }
```

Tentativa com o evento propertyChange e mouseClicked no campo data de admissão.

```
if(dataAdm().getDate().after(dataNasc.getDate())){
    mensagem de alerta;
}
```

Print da tela

[image: Imagem de exemplo dos campos]

actionPerformed

```
 validacao = new ValidaSuper();
        if (validacao.recebeDadosObrigatorios(nome.getText(), cpf.getText(), orgaoExp.getText(),
                funcao.getText(), email.getText())) {
            if (validacao.validaDadosObrigatorios()) {
                if(dataAdm.getDate().after(dataNasc.getDate())){
                    if(dataDem.getDate().after(dataAdm.getDate())){
                        setDadosObrigatorios();
                        setDados();
                        idCoord = map.insereCoordenador(coord);
                        map.insereTelefoneCoordenador(tel, idCoord);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Coordenador(a) inserido(a) com sucesso !!!");
                        limparCampos();
                    }
                }
            }  
        } 
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CadastraCoordenador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CadastraCoordenador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Há várias formas de fazer, coloca algum código do que você pelo menos tentou para dar um norte a quem for responder.

Comment: O link da imagem que você enviou está quebrado. Você pode usar o botão de anexar imagem no próprio formulário de pergunta.

Comment: Obrigada pelos comentários.

Comment: Mal pergunte, mas o correto não seria a diferença entre ano de nascimento e ano de admissão não ser menor que 14 anos? Levanto em conta que se trata de informações empregatícias.

Comment: Na verdade @DiegoF teria que ser 18 anos por ter carteira registrada, mas seu raciocínio está correto também. A questão é como validar essa questão que vc falou e a questão da data de demissão e data de admissão.

Comment: Onde você valida isso? Tem algum JButton que você clica e valida tudo antes de salvar? Se sim, poste o `actionPerformed` na pergunta pra gente verificar.

Comment: Primeiramente eu validava no botão de cadastrar. Isso mesmo.

Comment: Você tem que tratar isso dentro do `actionPerformed` do seu JButton. A logica não parece está errada, ou o problema não está no código que você adicionou na pergunta.